# long attribute value of HTML

Tags: html, asp.net

I am wondering why some of the tags attribute values have such a long string of values, such as

```
<script src="default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_sm1_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.51116.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3afd384f95-1b49-47cf-9b47-2fa2a921a36a%3a475a4ef5%3aeffe2a26%3a7e63a579%3a5546a2b%3ad2e10b12%3a37e2e5c9%3a1d3ed089%3a497ef277%3aa43b07eb%3a751cdd15%3adfad98a5%3a3cf12cf1%3a5a682656%3abfe70f69" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or sometimes the id of a tag has a long string of value too.

why is that? is that correct or normal? is that possible to decrease the size of that attribute so that i can somehow lower the load of server when it loads the page?

Answer (score 2):

> why is that?

Because a bunch of state data is being passed to the server

> is that correct

Yes

> or normal?

For ASP.NET it is

> is that possible to decrease the size of that attribute so that i can somehow lower the load of server when it loads the page?

Possible? Yes. Easy? Probably not as it looks like it does stuff deep inside ASP.NET.

The effort involved (both in writing the code to do so and running it) won't be worth it. It does not take a great deal of server resource to parse a 400 character query string.

Comment: thanks, for id of a control, set clientIdMode will be helpful to decrease the size of the string?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean why does ASP.NET bloat html with long attributes or Ids, that's how web forms works, it's ugly but don't worry about your server load.

You can control the way Ids are assigned to controls by changing the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property.

Comment: oh yeah, that clientidmode is what i think of using.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about your question but don't worry too much about it, the impact on the load of that amount of characters is absolutely negligible (except if you run your website on a toaster).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is affecting the script tags exclusively. It seems that you are using [Telerik' RadScriptManager's Combining Scripts feature](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-combine-scripts.html).

If you want to reduce the size of the tags (which is not a **real** problem), you might disable the feature.